# Find path of Python installed by Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I have installed python `3.8.6` with homebrew on macOS. But when I check with `which -a python3` I only get paths of `3.9` and `3.8.2`.

Is there a way to find the paths of all versions installed by homebrew? Or maybe more general question, how can I find the path of `3.8.6`?

[image: install python]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `brew info <packagename>`

it's probably in one of (and referenced in both)

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_2
/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/libexec/bin
```

See also [Apple SE Where can I find the installed package path via brew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145437/where-can-i-find-the-installed-package-path-via-brew)

If it's not there, it's plausible the version detection is wrong and only searches for the first two version digits (as conflicting versions may clobber each other). In this case, follow the warning and reinstall the specific version you want.

Comment: Thank you, `brew info python@3.8` gave me the correct path eventually, which is: `/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3`